# Aggregate in SQL with calculated key

Tags: sql, database, sas

I would like some suggestion for my SAS SQL Code.
Suppose I have long format table with 4 Columns. There are multiple account, multiple date as follow:

```
ACCOUNT DATE      STAGE AMOUNT
A001    01DEC2020   1   100000
A001    01JAN2021   1   100000
A001    01FEB2021   1   100000
...     ...        ...  ...
```

What I am trying to do is I created sequential order column, named `RANK` by starting from 1 by `ACCOUNT` and `DATE`. Then, I will create `YEAR` column by `CEIL(RANK / 12)`. After that I will create `OS` Column by condition `WHEN CASE`.

The final table that I needed to aggregate columns `GROUP BY ACCOUNT, YEAR`.
However, the result is not followed as expecting. I got multiple duplicated rows after running the code.

Below is my code from SAS SQL. SAS is not allow to use `RANK() OVER(PARTITION)`.

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE workingData (DROP = RANK OS) AS SELECT
    ACCOUNT,
    STAGE,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.DATE)
        FROM loanData b
        WHERE b.DATE <= a.DATE
            AND a.ACCOUNT eq b.ACCOUNT) as RANK,
    CEIL(CALCULATED RANK / 12) as YEAR,
    CASE
        WHEN CALCULATED RANK = 1 THEN a.AMOUNT
        ELSE 0
        END AS OS,
    CALCULATED YEAR,
    MAX(OS) AS OUTSTANDING,
    MEAN(AMOUNT) AS EAD 
    FROM loanData a
    GROUP BY ACCOUNT, CALCULATED YEAR
    HAVING STAGE = 2
        OR (STAGE = 1 AND CALCULATED RANK <= 12)
            OR (STAGE = 3 AND CALCULATED RANK = 1)
    ORDER BY ACCOUNT, YEAR
    ;
quit;
```

The result is shown below:

```
ACCOUNT STAGE YEAR OUTSTANDING EAD
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A002    2   1   50000   40669.25
A002    2   1   50000   40669.25
A002    2   1   50000   40669.25
...     ... ... ...     ...
```

But what I expected is:

```
ACCOUNT STAGE YEAR OUTSTANDING EAD
A001    1   1   100000  100000
A002    2   1   50000   40669.25
A002    2   2   0       32024
A002    2   3   0       23888
A003    3   1   40000   40000
...     ... ... ...     ...
```

Any suggestion on the process that I have just only one chuck of SQL to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev In which statement? I tried SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT, resulting in nothing changed from my code example.